# get a dict from subset of namedtuple

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, namedtuple

I would like to convert subset of namedtuple into one dictionary. like following I have Namedtuple as Const. but i would like to create a dictionary like `{'typeB':'value_typeB', 'typeC':'value_typeC'}`. is there a better way to do it?

```
from collections import namedtuple
Namedtuple = namedtuple('Namedtuple', ['typeA', 'typeB', 'typeC', 'typeD'])
Const = Namedtuple(typeA='value_typeA', typeB='value_typeB', typeC='value_typeC', typeD='
a = {k: v for k, v in Const._asdict().items() if k in ['typeB', 'typeC']}
print(a)
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: like more straightforward way to do it, instead of iterate and check. because what if I have more than 20 items in dictionary and would like to get 10 item from it...the line will be pretty long

Comment: you can always create a list dynamically with the keys you're interested in and use it for the `if k in ...` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access the values with key in a variable use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin function

```
a = {k: getattr(Const, k) for k in ['typeB', 'typeC']}
```